# Get the size of a variable in assembly language at runtime

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to obtain the size of a register (in bytes) at runtime in x86 assembly language, but I don't know if it's possible yet. In x86 assembly language, is it possible to obtain the size of a register at runtime? For example, is it possible to obtain the size of a register or variable (such as `ebx`), and move it into another register (such as `eax`)?

When I tried to run the instruction `mov bx, sizeof bx`, the MASM assembler produced the following error: `1>p4.asm(57): error A2009: syntax error in expression`.

Comment: This search query didn't give me any useful results, so I hope this question won't be downvoted for lack of research effort: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Get+the+size+of+a+variable+in+assembly+language+at+runtime&oq=Get+the+size+of+a+variable+in+assembly+language+at+runtime&gs_l=hp.3...658.658.1.1117.1.1.0.0.0.0.58.58.1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.7.hp.VqVN4q5jEYs&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmQ&fp=b736816b12004333&biw=1366&bih=639

Comment: When I tried to run the instruction `mov bx, sizeof bx`, the MASM assembler produced the following error: `1>p4.asm(57): error A2009: syntax error in expression`

Comment: You should ask the actual question, i.e. what are you trying to achieve. *Why* do you need the "size of register"? This operation does not make sense.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I suppose it would be more useful to obtain the size of a variable in bytes than the size of a register in bytes - I was just wondering whether it would be possible to obtain the size of a register as well as the size of a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just do

```
mov eax, 4 ; eax = size of ebx in bytes
```

CPU registers aren't flexible in size, they're fixed.

As for the variables, simply add a label after your variable and use the difference, something like this:

```
mystring db "blah blah blah",10,0
mystringend label $ ; or simply "mystringend:"
...
mov eax, mystringend - mystring ; or "offset mystringend - offset mystring"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are programming x86 assembly, the general purpose registers (including `eax` and `ebx`) are always 32-bit words. There are instructions to access the lower 16-bits of each register, and each byte of those 16-bits separately, but you must explicitly use them and keep track of the size of the expected size of the data in each register yourself. A caveat: if you are doing x86_64 programming, then the registers are extended to 64-bits, and the name changes from for example `eax` to `rax` or `r0`.

There are also no such things as variables in assembly; when you reference a memory address, there are encoded in the opcode bits that tell the process whether the memory access is a byte, a word, a dword, or larger. If you are using an assembler like MASM, then you can "declare" variables to have a certain size and then the assembler will keep track of basic type-checking for you, but the processor itself has no way of knowing the "size" of variables.